# What are my options in terms of implementing a WPS server?

Tags: software-recommendations, wps, ogc, pywps

I know about PyWPS, are there any good alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interesting resource on the support of OGC standards throughout the industry:
http://www.opengeospatial.org/resource/products/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at:

http://zoo-project.org/

[http://52north.org/](http://52north.org/maven/project-sites/wps/52n-wps-webapp/)

Comment: Have you made any (positive) experiences with the zoo project so far? I tried to set up a simple WPS today, and it seems to segfault upon every tiny mistake. Plus it doesn't even seem to support unicode.

Answer (score 2):

ZOO has a new kernel which works way better now. Additionally, the FOSS4G 2010 workshop material is available here: http://zoo-project.org/trac/wiki/ZooWorkshop2010/Content